# Return only specific columns of a polymorphic relationship? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

is there any way that I can only get specific columns back of my polymorphic relationship?

I want to make an Api Call to retrieve a Customer but I dont want to retrieve all the data of the User just the id and the username of it.

Here ary my Models:

User:

```
public function userable()
{
    return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'model_type', 'model_id');
}
```

Customer:

```
public function user()
{ 
    return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'model');
}
```

I dont want to work with hidden inside of the User Model because for other Api Calls i need all information of the User.

Comment: Eloquent `select`?

Comment: Take a look at the map->[only()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-only) method for collections

Comment: Look at API resources to format the data as you want for the API response: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get the value of attributes in polymorphic relations:

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->user()->value('your_key');
```